# How to make `html.customData` setting works on PHP?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have custom elements that I want to register on html auto-completion.

I appended `html.customData` on workspace settings (`.vscode/settings.json`) with my html custom data.

It works on HTML files but does not works on PHP files.

Comment: I don't think the PHP extension has much integration with the builtin html extension.